# Formula to calculate the probability of rolling an N-sided die M times and getting X or more of any single number?

Tags: probability

Let's say I have a fair 12-sided die. If I roll it 8 times, you can calculate the odds of rolling any single number, say, 4 or more times.

Running a simulation, I get that it's about p≈0.031

What, then, is the formula to calculate the probability of rolling a fair N-sided die M times and getting any single number X or more times?

This isn't a homework question. The specific example came up in a project I was working on, and I would like to have a formula for the general case instead of having to run simulations.

Comment: Hint: the binomial distribution.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability of throwing n different numbers in m throws of a dice](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262862/probability-of-throwing-n-different-numbers-in-m-throws-of-a-dice)